# How to Use Jackson in Java and Bluej

Tags: java, jackson, bluej

I need to convert an object I have to Json format, to do that I downloaded jackson-core-2.9.5.jar file and added it to libraries in Bluej using:
Tools->preferences->libraries->Add file, I then restarted Bluej.

Then in my class file I added:

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
```

The thing is when I try to Serialize the object to Json using:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
```

I get:

> cannot find symbol - class ObjectMapper

Am I using the wrong import? or there is something else I should do in Bluej?

Comment: You should also add jackson-annotations.jar and jackson-databind.jar to the class path.

Comment: thanks, I now have them along with  jackson-core-2.9.5.jar in class path but still nothing changed, is there something else I should do?

Comment: is it possible to add complete exception stack trace?

Comment: Have you added import for the ObjectMapper? `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`

Comment: that fixed it! thanks

Comment: Use modern IDE with autoimport

Answer (score 1):

You need this dependency for ObjectMapper

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

- In case you want to downlaod `jackson-databind` jar here is the [link.](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.5/)
- Also you need to add `jackson-annotations` jar as well on classpath if you are manually adding jars download [link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.5/).

Comment: how do I add it in Bluej? I did not find an xml file containing dependencies within the project files

Comment: thanks for the update, tried it but still nothing changed

Comment: Add both jar and check